# Wso2 API Manager : Reading Query Parameter in Sequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I  have an api with query parameter:

```
http://host:9080/xpress/services/getdata?recLimit=10
```

trying to read it in squence/custom mediator. please advise whether following syntax is correct ? Thank you.

```
<property name="recLimit" expression="$url:recLimit" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should work.

Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Synapse+XPath+Variables#SynapseXPathVariables-$url

Another options is

```
<property name="uri.var.val1" expression="get-property('uri.var.recLimit')"></property>
```